# Force data-role="page" to ALWAYS do a 100% height regardless of orientation

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I tried working on this on CSS and jquery but everything fails. Is there a default way to ALWAYS keep the data-role page or content to display in 100% HEIGHT?

Every single time i do a portrait mode and the content inside the data-role="content" is short, it leaves a nasty white space. please see capture attached.

[image: Please help]

Comment: Fixed Header/Footer? Might try adding the attribute data-fullscreen="true" http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/toolbars/bars-fullscreen.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQueryMobile to work out the height of the viewport, then take away the header and footer div heights. You are left with the height you require.

**HTML - for each page**

```
<body onload="init()">
    <div data-role="page" id="page" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Header text</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="page-content">
            <div data-role="content">
                <h1>Content here...</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <h1>More content here...</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>Footer text</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
// Function called when page has loaded
function init() {
  document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
}

// Function called when phonegap is ready
function onDeviceReady() {
    //All pages at least 100% of viewport height
    var viewPortHeight = $(window).height();
    var headerHeight = $('div[data-role="header"]').height();
    var footerHeight = $('div[data-role="footer"]').height();
    var contentHeight = viewPortHeight - headerHeight - footerHeight;

    // Set all pages with class="page-content" to be at least contentHeight
    $('div[class="page-content"]').css({'min-height': contentHeight + 'px'});
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"></div>
<div data-role="content">
   Content Goes here            
</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" ></div>
```

data-position="fixed" will always make the header and footer stick to top and bottom of the screen and content will be occupied by the renaming area

Comment: Great ! I was actually looking for a script free solution

Answer (score 1):

Try to append the backgoround image to the body or html element.

Comment: Or just a background colour the same as the bottom colour in the gradient. Good answer, +1.

Comment: i tried that as well, but it's not as plush as i hoped it would look like.

Comment: Try to set `html, body{ height: 100%};` and also the wrapper containing this all to `#wrapper: {height: 100%; min-height: 100%!importantM}`

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is your page is with either default data theme or you are using data-theme = "c". Try using:

```
Use data-theme="a" on your page
```